# Tokenised Dataframe with expected string

Tags: python

I am currently trying to tokenise my data frame but an error message saying that there is an 'expected string or bytes-like object'

My code was:

```
#Define empty list of tokens
all_tokens = []

for i in range(free.shape[0]):
    all_tokens = all_tokens + free['tokens'][i]
```

I was wondering if anybody could suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you give us more code to make this reproduceable and / or data? I mean what is "free"?

Comment: Why don't you provide a string or bytes-like object where the error message tells you it is expected?

Comment: Free is the dataframe I am using. Also what do you mean by providing a string or bytes-like object. I am still quite new to python and coding